# How would I write a SQL query to include monthly counts for all categories with all months and categories showing even if no records exist

Tags: sql, reporting-services, grouping, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SSRS and I'm trying to populate a report to show monthly counts grouped by categories.   The report should have the categories listed as row headers and all months of the year shown as column headers.  The requirement is that I need to display all months and categories regardless if there is data that falls within those columns/rows.

My problem is constructing the SQL query to do just that.

Here are examples of the tables I'm working with:

Transaction table:

```
create table [Transaction] (
     ContactID int Primary Key
     , CategoryID int
     , DateKey int
)
```

Calendar table:

Note that this table was originally created as a Date Dimension to be used with SSAS but I decided not to use SSAS as cube development was getting overwhelming for me.  There are many other fields in this table but these are the fields of importance regarding this issue.

```
create table [Calendar] (
     DateID int Primary Key
     , Date datetime
     , Year nchar(4)
     , Month nvarchar(2)
)
```

Category table:

```
create table [Category] (
     CategoryID int Primary Key
     , CategoryName nvarchar
)
```

The query needs to return a dataset to be used in SSRS to populate a report similar to the following:

```
Category   |   Jan  |  Feb  | Mar  |  Apr  |  May  |  June  | etc...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Category A |   -    |   -   |  -   |   -   |   -   |   -    | etc...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Category B |   -    |   -   |  -   |   -   |   -   |   -    | etc...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Category C |   -    |   -   |  -   |   -   |   -   |   -    | etc...
```

I know that it involved some combination of OUTER JOINS,  GROUP BY,  and subqueries.  I just can't wrap my head around how to accomplish this.

I'd be very happy if someone could assist me in this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query gets all the categories in the transactions.  It is pivoting on the month, by extracting the month from the date and counting the number of transactions.  This will return a row for all categories in the data

```
select c.categoryName,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Mar,
       . . . 
from transaction t join
     category c
     on t.categoryID = c.categoryID 
group by categoryName
order by categoryName
```

If you actually need *all* categories, even when there are no transactions at all, then use a right outer join:

```
select c.categoryName,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
       sum(case when extract(month from date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Mar,
       . . . 
from transaction t right outer join
     category c
     on t.categoryID = c.categoryID 
group by categoryName
order by categoryName
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply!  Your my hero!  I was able to get this to work, although I do see now why SSAS and MDX makes these queries much easier though the learning curve is pretty steep.   Just to note I wasn't able to use the 'extract' function.  I used Month(date) instead.   I believe extract is MySql code?  Anyhow it works and very thankful.  In time I too will be a SQL Guru.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `PIVOT` function:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  CategoryName,
            Calendar.[Month],
            ContactID 
    FROM    Category
            LEFT JOIN [Transaction] 
                ON [Transaction].CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
            LEFT JOIN Calendar
                AND [Transaction].DateKey = Calendar.DateID
)
SELECT  CategoryName, 
        [1] AS [Jan],
        [2] AS [Feb],
        [3] AS [Mar],
        [4] AS [Apr],
        [5] AS [May],
        [6] AS [Jun],
        [7] AS [Jul],
        [8] AS [Aug],
        [9] AS [Sep],
        [10] AS [Oct],
        [11] AS [Nov],
        [12] AS [Dec]
FROM    Data
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(ContactID)
            FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
        ) pvt
```